# Object.assign overwritten outside of constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, preact

I'm having a rather strange issue. I'm using TypeScript and Preact to create a Button component. I'm using a TypeScript interface for prop validation, essentially and using a constant variable as the "default" props. The props are then applied using Object.assign and passed to super. Here is the code as follows:

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import { Component, h } from "preact";

export interface ButtonProps {
  color?: string;
  type?: "primary" | "secondary";
}

const ButtonPropsDefaults: ButtonProps = {
  color: "primary",
  type: "primary",
};

export default class Button extends Component<PButtonProps> {

  constructor(props: ButtonProps) {
    // Logs { color: "primary", type: "primary" }
    console.log(ButtonPropsDefaults);

    super(Object.assign(ButtonPropsDefaults, props));

    // Logs { color: "primary", type: "primary", children: {...} }
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  public render() {
    // Logs { children: {...} }
    console.log(this.props);

    const className = classNames({
      "button": true,
      [`button--color-${this.props.color}`]: !!this.props.color,
      [`button--type-${this.props.type}`]: !!this.props.type,
    });

    return <button className={className}>{this.props.children}</button>;
  }

}
```

Notice the results of the console.log statements. It seems like the value "reverts" back to the original state as passed in to the constructor. So, for example, if I were to use the component as `<Button color="primary">Test</Button>`, the console.log statement in the render function will be `{ color: "primary", children: {...} }`.

Thanks for reading and I appreciate any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

You want merge the props and your default props into a new object. So you can do

```
super(Object.assign({}, ButtonPropsDefaults, props)) or
super({...ButtonPropsDefaults, ...props})
```

Comment: Object.assign({}, ButtonPropsDefaults, props) and the spread operator both result in the same issue.